# I want to enable SSL/HTTPS for icCube 6.8.5 Server

Tags: iccube

I need to enable the SSL/HTTPS for icCube 6.8.5 server. Have been following the below link. So, far I am able to launch using http. But after passing the sslPortNumber in icCube.xml, its not enabling the HTTPS protocol. Now its becoming really hectic.
Can someone please help me out with the required steps for enabling the https ?

Please note that I tried following the link. For example I have created a self signed certificate using the link, but didnt find any option as how or where to use this certificate.

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html

```
    <!--
                -1 means the SSL (i.e., HTTPS) connector is not activated.
            -->
            <sslPortNumber>-1</sslPortNumber>

            <!--
                Consistent with Jetty 9.x configuration :

                        http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html

                An optional path to the key store when using the SSL connector.

                (not relevant if SSL port number = -1)
            -->
            <sslKeyStorePath/>

            <!--
                See Jetty documentation to generate an OBF: value

                    java -cp jetty-util-9.0.6.v20130930.jar org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password your-password
                    java -cp jetty-util-9.0.6.v20130930.jar org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password OBF:your-obfuscated-password

                If not specified, the value will be prompted on the console.

                (not relevant if SSL port number = -1)
            -->
            <sslKeyStorePassword/>

            <!--
                Defaulted to JKS (others JCEKS, PKCS12, ...).

                (not relevant if SSL port number = -1)
            -->
            <sslKeyStoreType/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> its not enabling the HTTPS protocol.

Any error in the logs ?

> ... a self signed certificate using the link, but didnt find any option as how or where to use this certificate.

Should be in the key store as referenced by: sslKeyStorePath.

Comment: Thank you @marcPolizzi  for looking into this.How to define the sslKeystorePath in icCube.xml ? I mean is there any proper sytax to define the path in xml file
Here is the error that I am getting while triggering the https url

Comment: load-schema-on-startup] [DEBUG] (18-01-19 11:42:18.448 IST) [R] GWT 6 request-process-started [session:80736568-0c77-48f9-bbf7-35920758b761] LOAD (schema:none) GwtLoadSchemaQuery cl_GWT_GwtLoadSchemaQuery_1547791938448_331313246
[               pool-2-thread-1]
 [ERROR] (18-01-19 11:42:18.557 IST) Unexpected Error
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to license1.icCube.com:80 [license1.icCube.com/178.79.157.7] failed: Connection refused: connect at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)

Comment: It's a file path. This error is not related to configuring icCube. Contact directly their support for more help.